# Error After occured after updating angular2 Beta 11

Tags: angular

@View not working after updating angular2 beta.8 to beta11. I am getting this error in termial

```
ERROR in ./~/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/yearpicker.ts
(2,14): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.

ERROR in ./~/ng2-bootstrap/components/datepicker/monthpicker.ts
(2,14): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.

ERROR in ./src/app/components/subrouting/sub-routing.ts
(1,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.

ERROR in ./src/app/components/sub-routing-2/sub-routing-2.ts
(1,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.

ERROR in ./src/app/components/access-directives/access-directives.ts
(1,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.

ERROR in ./src/app/components/access-data-bt-component/send-data.ts
(1,20): error TS2305: Module '"/home/dinesh/dev/angular2-seed-with-gulp/node_modules/angular2/core"' has no exported member 'View'.
```

Comment: `@View decorator` was removed in beta-10 but change log doesn't say anything about it. Look at my comment in second link given by Gunter.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `@View` decorator was removed. The parameters set by `@View(...)` can be set by `@Component(...)` as well anyway.

See also
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7363
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7658