# Angular 2 - when should I use @View for loading a template?

Tags: angularjs, angular

In Angular 2 you can load a template in a @Component or a @View. Is there a best practice for this process?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error After occured after updating angular2 Beta 11](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36126193/error-after-occured-after-updating-angular2-beta-11)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `@View` is about to be removed so you should use the `@Component` one.

See this issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7495

Answer (score 1):

Never. It was removed in the latest beta (11). They just forgot to add it to the CHANGELOG

- https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/7707
- https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7658